# Regex to extract words from wiki-like scientific articles

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to extract only words from scientific articles in order to further analyse them. I have almost achieved the desired result by composing this Regex: `\b[^\d\W]+\b`
Here is what I have for now https://regex101.com/r/7YStbQ/1

However I also need domain names and similar words with punctuation within them like `merriam-webster.com.` or `et al.`, `etc.` to be excluded.

Another thing I want to achieve is to exclude all English prepositions, articles and other short language constructs that are not really meaningful (`the, a, an, in, out, or, by, with, and, is, on, of, at, to etc`). But I've read that there are more than 150 prepositions in English. So excluding at least the shortest of them will be great.)

What I've defined as a word in my case, it is a non-whitespace continuous sequence of letters. Basically I want to get only meaningful English words.
Looking for any hints and suggestions on how I may to improve my Regex.

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/7YStbQ/2

Comment: For list of preposition, is there any meaning full English word that is less than 3 char?  So a `{3,}` can help you reduce the preposition list. but ignoring word base on list of preposition is not a  regex work it's something you should do after.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, DragandDrop, thank you! Based on your suggestions I've modified the Regex and achieved almost what I needed. Here is the current result https://regex101.com/r/9gPhv1/1 There is still space for further improvements but it's better than what I've started with.

Comment: @DragandDrop There are such words. `ox`, `ad`, `Ed`, `cv`... I am afraid, OP will have to use a list. See https://regex101.com/r/7YStbQ/3